# Как я могу уменьшить отступ в Stack.Navigator / Stack.Screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function Root() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Main"
                          component={MainMenu}
                          options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Games"
                          component={Games}
                          options={{ headerShown: true,
                          }}
            />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
            <Drawer.Screen name="MainMenu" component={Root}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

У меня имеется подобная навигация, но между Drawer и Stack имеется большой разрыв, как я могу его уменьшить?

[image: Разрыв между MainMenu и Games]

Comment: Я опробовал в options задавать headerStyle и указывать height, margin и подобные команды, но ничего не работает, так как по документации там можно задать только fontSize и fontFamily

Answer (score 0):

Ппробуйте так:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
            margin: 0,
            // дополнительные стили через CamelCase, если нужно 
        },
    }}
>
```

Comment: <html>TS2322: Type '{ margin: number; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp&lt;{ backgroundColor?: string | undefined; }&gt;'.<br/>Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'margin' does not .

С последний обновлением это более не работает, и headerStyle можно только background задавать

Comment: Попробуйте так:
`<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Main" screenOptions={{ drawerStyle: { marginLeft: 0 } }}>`
или так:
`<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Main" screenOptions={{ contentContainerStyle: { marginLeft: 0 } }}>`

Comment: Не, ничего не меняется